# How to tell when/if brick foundation needs to be repointed?

Tags: foundation, brick, maintenance, repoint

My house's foundation is circa-1900 brick with lime mortar over a fieldstone base.

Should I consider repointing the brick a periodic maintenance task -- and if so, how can I tell when it should be done, or how often it should be scheduled for?

(In particular, I'm trying to decide whether I can get away with adding insulation to this part of the foundation, and I need to know how much access I would need to preserve.)

Comment: When you say "foundation", do you mean the part of the wall underground, or do you mean the above ground masonry upon which a wood (or similar) construction is built?

Comment: In my case, both. Fieldstone below frost line, about 6' of brick wall on top of that to about 2' above surface (painted outside, and I'm not seeing any obvious problems), then stick construction above that. If only houses came with real maintenance manuals...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lime mortar brickwork does need periodically repointing.  How often depends on the weather in your location (wet is bad, lots of freeze-thaw is bad, acid pollution is very bad), but I'd say probably every 20 to 40 years is about right.

If you cover the outside of the wall with insulation, then the mortar is largely protected from the weather, and is unlikely to need repointing.

I do have some concerns that moisture management in your house may depend on the moisture being able to evaporate away (compare with a modern house, where the Portland cement mortar is waterproof and the basic strategy is stop the water getting in in the first place).  Obviously if you have covered the walls with waterproof insulation, that stops rain wetting the wall, but there is still a potential problem with rising damp.  You may have a layer of slate in the wall.  This reduces water rising through the wall, but it doesn't eliminate it, and that water must have a way to escape.

Comment: Hm. I've been in the house 15 years. Gods know when repointing was last done. So it may be anywhere from midlife to overdue. Could just assume so I have a known baseline, but a way to know where I am on that spectrum would help... Currently uninsulated, and no plan to insulate the outside unless something much more major is needed; inside is possible but it sounds like the answer should be "repoint first because it'd be a mess to do second"

Comment: Is the mortar missing / cracked in places.  If so, it needs repointing; if not, not.  (Repointing lime mortar is quite easy, and very therapeutic.  Also, you don't need to worry about the mortar going off, so you can make up a reasonable sized quantity, store it in something sealed, and just use it up over a weekend or so.

Comment: Ok. Most of the mortar is presumably fine, then. I've already dealt with the area where settling had caused a significant separation. I probably should mortar the dry-stacked fieldstone layers at some point to help stabilize them and discourage critters, but that's presumably best done with modern cement. Now I need to deal with the cracking basement floor, but since I'm nervous about what's under it and about keeping things stable I'm gonna have a pro deal with that